# How to set the nonce in offline transaction?

Tags: signature, nonce, txpool

Let's suppose, I already executed 48 Tx onchain and I signed an offchain Tx with nonce 49.

Now, If:

- I don't sign the offchain Tx with nonce, the transaction will be
  invalid because every Tx must have nonce to protect against replay
  attach.
- I make an onchain Tx with 49 nonce, the offchain signed Tx
  will automatically get void as network will not accept
  another Tx with similar nonce.
- I make an onchain Tx with nonce 50
  (instead of 49 as stated above), my tx will stay in pending state
  until and unless a Tx with 49 nonce is not executed.

There are so many problems in Offchain signing of Tx. How to overcome these problems?